# How do I return the last primary key of the last added item in java?

Tags: java, database, methods, primary-key, return

Have  a linking (or ref) table which has a dual primary key. Need to return the last primary key which was auto generated from the current connection in a selected table. This is in java.
The database is in MS Access if that makes a difference.
Sorry for the rushed description, but our team is working to a tight schedule.

Any links or suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

EDIT:

The database is populated using SQL. We enter the data for one form, but we do not know the auto generated number. Need to find out what this was so it can be entered into the ref table. We only know half the composite key, which is why we need the second one.

Edit:

Re the best answer so far (cant seem to comment).
I get the following error...
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"

Any Advice?

Comment: Ouch about the UnsupportedOperationException.  It may be that Access doesn't support this operation.  Googling around, it seems like not all databases support this capability.  We had to use a different approach here at my work for Oracle since it doesn't have identity columns, for example.  If it's not too late to redesign your keys, try switching to UUID-based keys so that you can generate the keys in Java and push them into the database rather than having the db generate them.  Probably too late to make that change, though.

Comment: Ran out of time on this projet. does matter too muh. if anyone is interested in a workaround, there is one. save the reord to a seprate loation and the ompair it to the last saved reord, n then get that key if its the same, then the next last saved reord, et et, till you find the key. sorry my C key doesnt work for some reason, Cap only, wtf? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things.  First, you'll have to pass in an extra parameter when preparing your statement or executing your statement.  If you're using prepared statements, do the following:

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

If you're not using prepared statements, do the following when you call executeUpdate():

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

After you execute your statement, you can call

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()
```

This will give you a result set that contains any of the keys that were generated.

I haven't tried this approach with Access, but it works fine with SQL Server identity columns.

Comment: I am trying this myself using Java 1.7 with Access 2010 over ODBC, and I can confirm that I am also receiving a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExeption when calling the stmt.executeUpdate function.

Answer (score 2):

Statement.getGeneratedKeys() should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Put both values for the composite key into an array of Object with two elements and return that.

Alternatively, put the new composite key in the instance you just saved and return that.